# CORS not filtering anything out

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to see if CORS is working on my Django application.

I call my own API from a JS static file in my project.

After implementing CORS to not allow any requests to my API, I still am able to call the API successfully from my script. Shouldn't CORS reject my call since I'm not on the "ALLOWED_ORIGINS"?

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = []

MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
....
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
    'corsheaders',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS headers are used to signal web browsers which calls are allowed.

I wouldn't expect a CORS library to do any back-end verification.

So if you are testing your API entry points outside a browser, using a script, your CORS configuration should only be reflected in the headers sent.

CORS documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

`corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` documentation: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Comment: I think I mostly follow. But currently, my request headers includes `'Accept': '*/*'`. Shouldn't this be empty in this case since I've listed no allowed origins?

Comment: @bernardo No, `Accept` is about the content type (html, json, ...). You can see the CORS header in the response with the name `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: if I don't see that why could that be? My request headers are `['Host', 'Connection', 'Content-Type', 'Origin', 'Accept-Encoding', 'Cookie', 'Accept', 'User-Agent', 'Referer', 'Accept-Language', 'X-Request-Id', 'X-Forwarded-For', 'X-Forwarded-Proto', 'X-Forwarded-Port', 'Via', 'Connect-Time', 'X-Request-Start', 'Total-Route-Time', 'Content-Length']` and my only Response header is `'Content-Type'`

Answer (score 0):

As it seems your  code working fine it should reject your **HTTP request** JUST  try making same request in chrome(incognito)  If it worked ( reject your call ) then
just  clear your  browser cache

**NOTE** : make sure you are using `Python 3.7 to 3.11` and `Django 3.2 to 4.1`  as it's mentionned in  `django-cors-headers` [Requirements](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)

Comment: going incognito does not reject. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: what version of python and django-rest-framework you are using ?

Comment: djangorestframework==3.13.1
Python 2.7.18

Comment: this error because you are using  **Python 2.7.18** wich is not supported by  **django-cors-headers** i'l update my answer

Comment: Still does not fix the issue. Going incognito does not stop me from making requests when no requests should be allowed.

Comment: did you upgrade python  to a new version ??

Comment: yes @monim I did but the same issue persists